# How to paginate data with cloud firestore and javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

how can I paginate data from cloud firestore.
I would like to get data with a next button but disable the button when there is no more data to bring.

How do I know when I should disable the "next" button?
How do I know there is data behind to enable the "Previous" button?

I appreciate your help
Thanks

Comment: The API will not help you with this.  You should just request one more document than what you want to display, and if you get that extra document, then you know there is at least one more page with at least one more element.

Comment: Ok Thanks for that, but this works for the "next" button but for the "previous" button how could I use it?

Comment: If you've gone through pages in your app already, you can remember internally that you've done so.

Comment: that can work in case I only have two pages, but if I have more?

Comment: I suggest asking a new question with this specific scenario detailed, along with code that you've tried that isn't working the way you expect, or the specific case where you're stuck.

Comment: Ok, thanks @doug-stevenson for the help